# R plotting axis labels: Replacing Inf with unicode value for infinity \u221E

Tags: r, plot, unicode, axis-labels

In my plots I try to replace the axis labels with value 'Inf' with the infinity sign (e.g. unicode '\u221e'). Since I have many plots with different labels, I don't want to do it by hand. 
I thought it would be easier to use unicode than plotmath. However I can't figure out how to reach my goal. For example, I have the following vector:

```
xlab <- as.character(c(1:10,Inf))
x <- y <- 1:11
plot(x,y,xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=x,labels=gsub("Inf","\u221E",xlab))
axis(3,at=x,labels=gsub("Inf","\\u221E",xlab))
```

both don't work. What am I missing? Thank you for your help!

Edit on 2018-02-06:

I was wrong, rawr's solution works only halfway. I think I need to clarify my problem a bit more.

1) I have many different plots (with different `x`, `y` and corresponding `xlab` values) that I want to loop over. That's why I try to use a sub/gsub solution, because I don't want to write a hundred times the labels.

2) My first example (`axis(1,at=x,labels=gsub("Inf","\u221E",xlab))`) is not working on any of my windows machines. It is working on debian, though.

3) rawr's solution does have the problem that it annotates all available labels, no matter how much space there is available for annotating. Simple example:

```
x <- y <- exp(-1:11)
xlab <- as.character(c(Inf,10:-1))
plot(x,y,xaxt="n")
axis(1, at = x, labels = parse(text = gsub("Inf", "infinity", xlab)))
```

is not that nice.

Is there any solution for my windows machines? Possibly not by code, but by changing some settings?

Thanks!

Comment: first one works. you can also do `axis(1, at = x, labels = parse(text = gsub("Inf", "infinity", xlab)))`

Comment: Ok, thank you. First one doesn't work on my machine. So that's possibly a locale problem. Thanks for the parse solution, that definitely works!

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`axis(1, at=x, labels=c(1:10, expression(infinity)))`

A more flexible approach that can handle any unicode character is available using the `stringi` package:

`axis(1, at=x, labels=c(1:10, stri_unescape_unicode('\\u221E')))`

Comment: Yes, thank you. However, I don't want to do all the necessary changes by hand. that's why I'd like to avoid the expression/plotmath solution and go with unicode...

Comment: @Chris hmm, I don't know why one would insist on using a Unicode char when expression is more readable; nevertheless stringi has some alternatives. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see an easy, readable expression solution, but rawr's answer above using parse is great!